# Custom values in kendo grid "Items per page" dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with several 1000's of rows. I want to display them as 1000 per page. Can any one please tell me how can I make the dropdown customized with the values like 1000, 5000, 10000 etc. and display number of rows based on it in javascript or JQuery. For now am setting the page size to 1000 in javascript, but when I change it to 20 or 10 in dropdown, I am unable to get the 1000 back!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Javascript for kendogrid, add the following during your grid definition:

```
pageable: {
    pageSize: 1000,
    pageSizes: [1000, 5000, 10000]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
pageable: {
   pageSize: 10,
   buttonCount: 10,
   pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 500]
},
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!